# My solution to this exercise seems too easy; hints?

Tags: ios

I'm working through Big Nerd Ranch's *iOS Programming, 2nd Edition*, and I've come to the Chapter 4 Challenge: Heading.  The exercise offers a hint that I'm finding confusing; it says I need to do things that I don't think I need to do.

Up to this point in the chapter, the book has walked me through the concept of delegation, using CoreLocation as an example.  In the app delegate, I've added a CLLocationManager instance variable and set its delegate to be the app delegate.  See below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I've also implemented the two delegate methods for CLLocationManager, as follows:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}
```

Ok, so the chapter has walked me through all of this so far, and everything works nicely.  Now comes the exercise:

> "Using delegation, retrieve the heading information from the
>   **CLLocationManager** and print it to the console. (Hint: You need to implement at least one delegate method and send another message to the
>   location manager.)"

Here's where I'm confused.  First of all, after reading the CLLocationManager documentation, it appears as though there are no delegate methods to be implemented other than the two I've already done.  So I don't know what other delegate method the hint could be referring to.

Second of all, it seems as though I could solve the exercise simply by updating the implementation of locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
    // Updated code below
    CLLocationDirection heading = [newLocation course];
    NSLog(@"Heading: %f", heading);
}
```

So it seems to me as though I don't, in fact, need to send any more messages to the location manager (although I do need to send a getter message to newLocation; but that's a CLLocation, not a CLLocationManager).

So I'm clearly misunderstanding something.  I'm not looking for a solution---I do want to work this through---but I would very much appreciate a hint as to what I'm misunderstanding.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out that my copy of Xcode 4 only had the Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library documentation and not the iOS 4.3 Library docs.  This explains why all references to "heading" were missing, and so I couldn't find the appropriate delegate methods.  I've downloaded the appropriate docs, and now I know what happens when you take for granted that the documentation is complete.  Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are asking you to get the compass (magnetic) heading.

Look back at the CLLocationManager docs again. There are -startUpdatingHeading and -stopUpdatingHeading methods and corresponding delegate methods to get the compass heading from the device.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you believe that the documentation in my copy of Xcode 4 doesn't refer to locationManager:didUpdateHeading: method?  But if I search online, there it is!  Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, the exercise is meant to be done from scratch. You rely on what you learned so far in the chapter, but you are not extending the code provided in the chapter. So, when you count methods, you start from scratch and everything will match...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) documentation, there's a lot more than two methods that you can implement! :)

And as Firoze said, there's a difference between the movement direction and your heading.

You can go one way, but still look at an other direction. `CLLocationDirection` here represents where you're going, but it's not what you're looking for!

You can look at the beginning of the Overview in the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) documentation, where there's a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
      didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading